# apache returns status code 403, but serves page normally

Tags: apache

I am on setting up a website on a server, where I don't have access to apache conf files, nor apace logs.. Just the .htaccess. I'd like to map different routs to different paths on server

This is the contents of my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) website/v1/project_files/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) website/v1/project_files/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^media/(.*) website/v1/project_files/media/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^certs/(.*) website/v1/project_files/certs/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^errors/(.*) website/v1/project_files/errors/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule .* website/v1/index.php [L]
```

index.php gets executed normally, but the response code is 403. I changed the line `RewriteRule .* website/v1/index.php [L]` with `RewriteRule .* website/v1/index.html [L]` (and created index.html) and the response code was still 403 (and the content returned was correct.)

What is the cause of this error? I wish I could tell you what the error logs say but I do not have access. Server is running apache 2.4.43.

**UPDATE:**, if I remove all rewrites and conditions and leave just `RewriteRule .* website/v1/index.php [L]`, than it executes php correctly, serves status code 200, but ofcourse, does not serve any css, media, js files because it cannot find them.

Comment: the problem  most likely is in your php code, not apache. Most probably somewhere you output a php header 403, look it up

Comment: I replaced the .php file with .html with nothing but a "It works" string in it. The server still responded with 403 and served "It works" string

Comment: then check the folder permissions and permissions on resources in youjr apache config and/or other htacess that might interfere

Comment: See my update, that solely removing some rewrites triggers 200 status code.

Comment: Also checked all folder and files permissions. 755 on all of them

Comment: it is strange that 403 (forbidden) status is returnd yet the resource/page is returned as well

Comment: it is indeed bizarre